# Python UWSGI - which script launched?

Tags: python, flask, uwsgi, ini

I am taking over a website and we have the following paramters to the UWSGI process (Flask), I can't understand which script it does launch (which python script is used)... Any clue ?

```
[app:jispapi_app]
use = egg:JispApi#main


[pipeline:jispapi]
pipeline =
    tm
    jispapi_app

[filter:tm]
use = egg:repoze.tm2#tm
commit_veto = repoze.tm:default_commit_veto

[composite:main]
use = egg:Paste#urlmap
/api/v2 = jispapi

[server:main]
use = egg:Paste#http
host = 0.0.0.0
port = 6543

[uwsgi]
socket = /jispapi.v2.sock
pidfile = /jispapi.v2.pid
virtualenv = /webapps/python/v2
pythonpath = /webapps/python/v2/apps/JispApi
enable-threads = true
processes = 2
master = true
harakiri = 60
daemonize = /log/uwsgi/jispapi.v2.log
post-buffering = 8192
uid = uwsgi
gid = uwsgi
manage-script-name = true
chmod-socket = 666
env = PYTHON_EGG_CACHE=/jaccede/.python-eggs
spooler = /webapps/python/v2/apps/JispApi/spooler
```

Comment: http://pythonpaste.org/deploy/

A config file has different sections, like app:main or filter:errors – 
• the part after the : is the “name” of the section
• the part before gives the “type”. 
• Other sections are ignored.
• # is a comment.

Typically you have one or two sections, named “main”: 
1. an application section ([app:main]) 
2. a server section ([server:main]). 
3. [composite:...] signifies something that dispatches to multiple applications (example below).